# How to assert a textview that displays only for few seconds in espresso automation

Tags: android-espresso

I'm trying to automate a flow which displays a textview for about 5 seconds. I'm unable to assert that text. Any help?

I tried using uiautomator and few other options. Nothing worked so far. Appreciate yo I r help in answering